# WEBrick fails to start default rails app: "uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Format"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, webrick

I'm trying to begin Ruby on Rails development on a Windows machine, but I can't get WEBrick to start the default Rails app.

Here's the output from my attempt to create and start the app:

```
C:\Users\my_user>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\wkspc>rails new sample_app
[...]
Bundle complete! 11 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\wkspc>cd sample_app

C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\wkspc\sample_app>rails server
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at bin/rails:4)
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Format
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:13:in `<module:TypeCast>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:7:in `<module:Jdbc>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:4:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:3:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:1:in `singleton class'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:70:in `<class:singleton class>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:68:in `<module:JdbcColumn>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:12:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:2:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:1:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:1:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:1:in `<module:(root)>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:9:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:1:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:1:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:52:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:52:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:3:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:3:in `block in (root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc.rb:1:in `each'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc.rb:1:in `block in (root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc.rb:9:in `each'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc.rb:9:in `(root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.20/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:1:in `(root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.20/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:2:in `<top>'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in `block in (root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `tap'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `<top>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<top>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

  block in require at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1593
  block in require at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1593
           require at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70
           require at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102
             <top> at C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/wkspc/sample_app/config/application.rb:7
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:944
   block in (root) at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1
               tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1743
            server at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88
            server at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85
             <top> at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:944
             <top> at bin/rails:4
```

It appears as though the problem is coming from the gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', and the error indicates
`uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Format`

Have I skipped some important configuration step? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't look like you ran `rake db:create` to create the DB.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's probably a good place to start: I just tried running `rake db:create`, and interestingly it outputs the same error as above, as if I had run `rails server` again.

Comment: Interesting. You might want to take a look at [gorails](https://gorails.com/dashboard) for setting everything up. They have guides for all platforms i.e. (OS X, Linux, Windows) I noticed that you are on windows. So this might be a good place to start. Here is the [guide](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10)

Comment: Yeah I tried RailsInstaller and was hoping I would be able to just go from there. Might have to uninstall and try gorails. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JayKelner you should update the answer as the accepted answer no longer is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/700), activerecord-jdbc-adapter is still having compatibility issues in Rails 5. There is a branch for rails-5 you can use by using this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :git => "https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git",
                                 :branch => "rails-5"
```

Comment: Thanks, that issue looked promising. Sadly, adding that to my Gemfile yields `[...] fatal: read error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Got it. The problem was with the way we tried to specify the repo. Here's what fixed it: I replaced the line `gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'` in my Gemfile with `gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :git => "https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git", :branch => "rails-5"` . Then, I ran `bundle install` and `rails server` and it's now working. Many thanks!

Comment: `git_source(:github) { |repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git" }; gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '~> 1.3.21', github: 'jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter', branch: 'rails-5'`

Comment: (Released gem is still broken.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to use the target `branch: 'rails-5` (which has been removed from the repo. I also was having compatibility issues when as well as using a specific version `gem activerecord-jdbc-adapter "1.3.20"`

The oldest tag that still supports rails v5.0.0.1 in the `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` repository is `50.1`

I updated the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '50.1'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '50.1'
```